# How to efficiently handle external requests in Laravel to avoid worker idling?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel job that requires making an external request which can take up to a minute to respond. I want to prevent my workers from idling and wasting resources during this time. Ideally, I would like to retire the worker after making the request and then process the response in a separate job.

Here's the basic workflow I'm looking for:

1. A job makes an external request.
2. The worker is retired and available for other jobs while waiting for the response.
3. Once the response is received, the data is put into another job for processing.

Is there a way to achieve this natively in Laravel?

**I decided to test the Http::async() to see if this resolved the issue.**

Having the two jobs "SendRequest" and "ProcessResponse". In this example, ProcessResponse has nothing in the __construct or handle. It is only meant to see if the job is dispatched.

```php
// SendRequest.php
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $promise = Http::async()->get('https://api.dicebear.com/6.x/bottts/png')->then(function ($response) {
            echo "Response received!";
            ProcessResponse::dispatch($response->body());
        });
    }
```

Using the above code snippet, ProcessResponse never gets dispatched.
[image]

```php
// SendRequest.php
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $promise = Http::async()->get('https://api.dicebear.com/6.x/bottts/png')->then(function ($response) {
            echo "Response received!";
            ProcessResponse::dispatch($response->body());
        });

        $promise->wait();
    }
```

Now, using the above code snippet instead, which just adds `$promise->wait()`, defeating the point of the async, the then() function does execute and ProcessResponse is dispatched.
[image]

This unfortunately shows that using async() is not a simple solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 basic options:

1. Webhook/Callback

   - Assuming that the service you're making the request against supports webhooks, once the task is complete the service issues an HTTP request back to a pre-configured URL for your service with status/results/what-have-you.
2. Polling

   - Assuming that the service you're making the request against can provide status information on running tasks, once your worker issues the request it can move on. However you need to have a background process of one kind or another that can poll task status, and trigger whatever needs to be done afterwards.
3. Sit and Wait

   - If the remote service doesn't support the above, and/or expects you to sit there with the connection open waiting for the response, then there's not much that you can do.

In any case, you will likely want to separate the pool of worker processes that actively serve requests to your app, [eg: web/FCGI workers] from the pool that handles long running/asynchronous/background tasks. [eg: queue/worker model]